# Add all usernames except current user's username to array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a follow friends view controller that loads all the usernames in the database, BUT I don't want it to load the current user's username. I need to access the username from the currentUser's uid, and add all the usernames that are not equal to it to my array.

[image: database structure]

```
@objc func loadData() {
    
    let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let query = rootRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
    
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            if username != rootRef.child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).value(forKey: "username") as! String{
                self.usernames.append(username)
            }
            print(username)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(self.usernames)
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes a user name the current name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and minimise queries inside loops, especially irrelevent ones. Given your database schema uses the users unique id as the key, you can run your evaluation based on that key using `child.key`.

```
@objc func loadData() {
        
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
        let query = rootRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
        
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
                let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                if Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid != child.key {
                    self.usernames.append(username)
                }
                print(username)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(self.usernames)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great answer Harry. And for Nicole: this code reads all `/users`. If you find yourself regularly only needing the user names, it's more efficient to store a node with just those: `/usernames`. That way you're downloading a lot less data that you don't read, leading to a lower bandwidth cost for you, and better performance (and possibly data charged) for your users.